# Can I write a java application for Login purpose?

Tags: java

I need to handle Login functionality to a particular site say `www.abc.com`. I had already registered to this particular site, hence can I give the username and password hardcoded in my application so that I can have connected to the server directly.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, you want to be able to login into a site that you have an account on via a java program?

Comment: if you want decent answers, you need to clarify this question.  At the moment, the only definite answer anyone can give is "yes you can".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Plain answer I would say Yes! , going into details there are many things to consider while making a java program for login many site needs HTTPs sessions and cookie handling, some also require JavaScript enabled browsers to handle login procedures. If you are making some kind of Robot App to login to that website and do some pre-assigned jobs. I would recommend you to consider using Embedded browser.

for Using browser in Java see http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/

Comment: @Vineet - he's only guessing about the OP wants to do.  For all we know, the OP could be trying to access a site with a RESTful web API ... which would render an embedded browser useless.

Comment: @Stephen, yes I knew that. The fact is the OP probably hasn't put much thought into what he would do after login.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is yes, but you might not want to do that. Also, why not use a https so that your users can login directly?

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  What is "a https"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write Java code to do that. Check http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html. Check http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html for examples. You can see there are examples for authentication as well.